# Is it possible to convert physical environments to virtual machines

Tags: virtualization

Is it possible to convert physical environments to virtual machines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### [VMware vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/)

This is the system I use when I go from physical to virtual systems.

> Automate and simplify physical to virtual machine conversions as well as conversions between virtual machine formats with VMware vCenter Converter. Use the intuitive wizard-driven interface of VMware vCenter Converter to transform your physical machines to virtual machines.
>
> - Convert Microsoft Windows and Linux-based physical machines and third-party image formats to VMware virtual machines.
> - Complete multiple conversions simultaneously with a centralized management console.
> - Minimize the number of steps to conversion with easy-to-use wizards.

Comment: yes, it is free.

Answer (score 5):

[**disk2vhd**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415) from System Internals may be what you are looking for.

> Disk2vhd is a utility that creates VHD (Virtual Hard Disk - Microsoft's Virtual Machine disk format) versions of physical disks for use in Microsoft Virtual PC or Microsoft Hyper-V virtual machines (VMs).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the system.

For Hyper-V try [P2V](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc764232.aspx).

For VMware, try the above.

iomega even has a neat product in this niche: [Vclone](http://www.ubergizmo.com/15/archives/2010/01/iomega-vclone.html)

Comment: windows systems?

Comment: windows as in hyperv?

or windows as in the OS family?  you can have windows inside vmware hypervisor if you like. no big deal. 

all the conversion products are free, so i say try all of them

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is [Paragon Backup & Restore](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/br-free/) (free) and [Acronis](http://www.acronis.eu/).

Both have VM creation, but the MS System Internals all work quite well, and 2 of the 3 are free!