# Possible to take a snapshot of a hard disc and use it in a Virtual Machine?

Tags: virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to convert physical environments to virtual machines](https://superuser.com/questions/114360/is-it-possible-to-convert-physical-environments-to-virtual-machines)

Hi,

A bit of a silly question really - but I was wondering would it be possible to take a snapshot of a OS you are running on a computer, the convert it or so it can be run as a virtual machine in VMware or Vitual Box?

Thanks!

Comment: Please note that this appears to be a duplicate of entry 114360, so you may want to read those posts as well.

Comment: Not a silly question at all. Probably one of the *top* questions from people starting out in virtualization.

Comment: ... and, yes, this is a duplicate question from this (http://superuser.com/questions/114360). It is best to avoid spreading answers across duplicate questions. Please put your *answers* there and vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VMware converter.  http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/  This will give you the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: +1 Also, Symantec Backup Exec System Recovery will  perform this task

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I thought it was a outrageous idea!